# Is there any way to access the matrixes using the (x,y) as index

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, np

I want to generate a matrix that stores the distance between every point with every other point. I want to be able to access this distance value in the matrix using the two coordinates.

As in the image below, I want to be able to access the distance using the points as the index.

matrix[point a, point b] = distance between two points

[image: The matrix with the euclidean distance between points]

Comment: Use a dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you would need a matrix of size defined by the maximum coordinate value. In your case, it would be a 10x10 matrix (symmetric). This would only work if your coordinates are positive integers, as in your example. For any other case, you need some kind of mapping array imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the `pandas` module.

- You can define column and index name with "*points coordinates*".
- Fill the data using the [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html)
- Access all the distances from one point using `df["[x, y]"]`
- Access a specific distance using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) on a column

---

**Full code + illustration**

```
# import modules
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

# input points
points = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6], [9, 10]]

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(cdist(points, points),
     columns=[str(p) for p in points],
     index=[str(p) for p in points])
print(df)
#             [1, 2]    [2, 3]    [3, 4]    [5, 6]    [9, 10]
# [1, 2]    0.000000  1.414214  2.828427  5.656854  11.313708
# [2, 3]    1.414214  0.000000  1.414214  4.242641   9.899495
# [3, 4]    2.828427  1.414214  0.000000  2.828427   8.485281
# [5, 6]    5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  0.000000   5.656854
# [9, 10]  11.313708  9.899495  8.485281  5.656854   0.000000

# select column "[2, 3]"
print(df["[2, 3]"])
# [1, 2]     1.414214
# [2, 3]     0.000000
# [3, 4]     1.414214
# [5, 6]     4.242641
# [9, 10]    9.899495

# get distance between point [2 3] and [1 2]
print(df["[2, 3]"].loc["[1, 2]"])
# 1.4142135623730951
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you request to solve it in numpy, you can use the [where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) clause. Here a sample:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[5,6],[9,10]])
distance_matrix = np.zeros((X.shape[0],X.shape[0]))
# distance matrix
distance_matrix[np.where(X==[1,2])[0][0],np.where(X==[1,2])[0][0]] = 0
distance_matrix[np.where(X==[1,2])[0][0],np.where(X==[2,3])[0][0]] = np.linalg.norm(np.array([1,2]) - np.array([2,3]))
distance_matrix[np.where(X==[2,3])[0][0],np.where(X==[1,2])[0][0]] = np.linalg.norm(np.array([1,2]) - np.array([2,3]))
```